# Blogger Popular Post can get data:post.url

Tags: html, xml, blogger

I have a popular posts widget on my Blogger template and the problem is even though the `data:post.title` is shown completely correct, `data:post.url` is returns nothing. So output becomes:

```
<a href="">Post title is shown</a>
```

Here is the full code of Popular Posts widget:

```
<b:widget id='PopularPosts1' locked='false' title='Popular Posts' type='PopularPosts'>
<b:includable id='main'>
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
    <a expr:href='data:post.url'><li><data:post.title/></li></a>
</b:loop>
</b:includable>
</b:widget>
</b:section>
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I replaced `data:post.url` to `data:post.href` and it worked! I don't know why there is such a difference while normal blog posts have `data:post.url` but popular posts doesn't.